# Where should I add my own code in the service template?

Tags: c++, windows, service, windows-services

Microsoft provides a [complete service sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/desktop/Services/the-complete-service-sample) to start with writing Windows services. However, I do not understand the following part from [this file](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/desktop/Services/svc-cpp) :

```
ReportSvcStatus( SERVICE_RUNNING, NO_ERROR, 0 );

// TO_DO: Perform work until service stops.

while(1)
{
    // Check whether to stop the service.

    WaitForSingleObject(ghSvcStopEvent, INFINITE);

    ReportSvcStatus( SERVICE_STOPPED, NO_ERROR, 0 );
    return;
}
```

I don't understand the point of the infinite loop containing a return statement. Doesn't it defeat the purpose ?

It seems to encourage to write the service content before the while loop but then, if we do not reach the following line :

```
WaitForSingleObject(ghSvcStopEvent, INFINITE);
```

... The service will not able to stop when the proper event is triggered, would it ?

Is this template flawed ? How can I make my service wait for an external trigger without making it impervious to stop calls ?

Comment: Is any of them macros that expands to `continue` or something?

Comment: There is no `continue` in the whole source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that example is not particularly well-written.  The main loop of the service is better written (conceptually) as:

```
// Main processing loop
while (!quit)
    do_work ();

ReportSvcStatus (SERVICE_STOPPED, NO_ERROR, 0);
return;
```

And in the service's control handler, you would have:

```
// CtrlHandler callback
DWORD WINAPI CtrlHandler (DWORD dwControl, DWORD  dwEventType, LPVOID lpEventData, LPVOID lpContext)
{
    ...
    if (dwControl == SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP)
        quit = true;
    return NO_ERROR;
}
```

Where `quit` is a global variable.

In practise (to avoid busy looping), the service probably normally sits around waiting on some sort of waitable object for something to do.  Let's imagine, for the sake of argument, that's a HANDLE called, say, `ghWakeupEvent`, created via [`CreateEvent()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms919029.aspx), and again stored in a global variable.

Then, the code becomes something like:

```
// Main processing loop
while (1)
{
    WaitForSingleObject (ghWakeupEvent, INFINITE);
    if (quit)
    {
        ReportSvcStatus (SERVICE_STOPPED, NO_ERROR, 0);
        return;
    }

    if (something_to_do)
        do_work ();
}

// CtrlHandler callback
DWORD WINAPI CtrlHandler (DWORD dwControl, DWORD  dwEventType, LPVOID lpEventData, LPVOID lpContext)
{
    ...
    if (dwControl == SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP)
    {
        quit = true;    // do this first!!
        SetEvent (ghWakeupEvent);
    }

    return NO_ERROR;
}
```

Note: no need for (or point in) `ghSvcStopEvent`.  The MSDN sample is a mixed-up mess.

Comment: This is exactly the answer I needed ! Thank you very much, much more helpful than the random intern at Microsoft who wrote this garbage of a sample.

Comment: @Norgannon ROFL.

Comment: Posted a documentation comment here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/Services/svc-cpp

Comment: @PaulSanders Thank you! I came from the MSDN example. Been scratching my head for 2 days almost to no avail :) The example is still salvageable I think, but it requires a bit of re-write in some places. Especially when it comes to putting meaningful content/work into a system service.

Comment: Worth mentioning perhaps: The signature for `CtrlHandler` is the one required by  `RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerEx` that uses the `LPHANDLER_FUNCTION_EX` callback typedef (with extended set of arguments). The MSDN example also left out this detail (it uses the non-Ex version).